# LEGO TECHNIC CyberMaster Software

Tags: mindstorms, technic, software

I come again to ask a favor. Can someone share the installation CD in English of LT 8482 CyberMaster or where can I download the software in English??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 10 mins on Google didn't turn up any place to download the software, but you can always buy a CD from one of the sellers on Bricklink:

http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=43378

You might be able to get one of them to upload the CD